# Working in local HG repo and pushing to remote GIT repo

Tags: git, mercurial

I need to have inter-operatebility between HG and git such that I can use hg repo and commands in my local repo but should be able to push local changes made via HG to remote GIT repository.
I have already tried reading some articles in stack overflow (about hg-git) and they didn't work exactly the way I wanted.
Practical examples would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Note: OS I work on is Ubuntu.

Comment: http://hg-git.github.io/ - what is unclear?

Comment: @planetmaker - I'm able to clone my git repo using the hg clone. Now the problem is that all the heads (as seen from tortoisehg) are marked as default branch and each head seem to have a tag which is actually the branch name. I can upgrade to branches using revision id and making changes and pushing works too. But seeing every head as default branch is bit to take in and might create lot of confusion while working.

Comment: @AkshayGuleria - it's **intended**, because Git-"branches" are not branches, but bookmarks really for all DVCS-world

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to work with bookmarks in hg as well. The problem is more or less resolved now.